# Could ISP limit my torrent bandwidth?

Tags: bittorrent, isp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I circumvent BitTorrent throttling?](https://superuser.com/questions/11176/how-can-i-circumvent-bittorrent-throttling)

Everyday i meet another problem. Seems like they will never end. i perform port forwarding both on the client and the router with regarding port numbers for BitTorrent. This time, i experience issues with my Bittorrent Client. im not an addict of torrent world. 3-4 months ago, i was able to download 4-5 GB size data through allowed/provided 8 Mbps download rate by ISP. The download speed could be about 700-800 KBps.However, today i tried many different files but couldnt exceed 100 KBps either files uploaded were new or old. Could ISP block it? how to overcome if this is the case?

Second question, why can't i download via torrent when HSS VPN activated?

Comment: See this...http://superuser.com/questions/11176/how-can-i-circumvent-bittorrent-throttling?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The bittorrent protocol is easily detected, even while encrypted, and it's relatively easy (on a technical level) for an ISP to throttle or reset bittorrent connections. There was a big issue with Comcast doing this a year or two back which actually got the FCC involved. Torrents themselves are also heavily dependent upon the size of the swarm backing them.

Comment: i know the swarm thing. But, once i activate HSS VPN to avoid this situation, i can't seem to download even any bits, why not?